# VisualSVN Server: Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am using a VisualSVN. Today I have reinstall the OS (Win2003 R2) and then install VisualSVN on it. I have imported repositories, check access with browser, everythig looks fine.

After that I tried to update existing chekouts. If I try that I get:

> Error: REPORT of
>   '/svn/SomeRepo/!svn/vcc/default':
>   Could not read chunk    Error: size:
>   Secure connection truncated
>   (https://serverbase:8443)

On server (in event viewer) I get the following error:

> Provider encountered an error while
>   streaming a REPORT response.

But if I do a new chekout, then it work properly. How to "connect" existing chekout with server? I do not want to delete them an do new co, sience they may contain unchekined content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your network connection.
2. Do you have another error messages on server? Like out of memory?

Comment: Network connection is unlikely to be the problem, because checkout works OK. If it were a connection problem, then checkout would have problems too.

Answer (score 0):

If checkout works OK, then your easiest option may be to make a clean checkout, then use a [file comparison tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool) like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to find and merge changes into the clean checkout. Make sure you configure Beyond Compare to ignore the .svn directories! I've used this technique on several occasions and Beyond Compare makes it quite straightforward.